# Faile to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, ajax

my web page runs normally, until i do a javascript AJAX snippet, it starts showing error 500 in cart function at the plus sign, when I click add it just increases the amount in the data and has to reload the page to see the number quantity, the user side won't see it

script in html

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js" integrity="" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Views.py

```
def add_to_cart(request):
    user = request.user
    product_id = request.GET.get('prod_id')
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    Cart(user=user, product=product).save()
    return redirect('/cart')
def show_cart(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = request.user
        cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=user)
        amount = 0.0
        shipping_amount = 10.0
        total_amount = 0.0
        cart_product = [p for p in Cart.objects.all() if p.user == user]
        if cart_product:
            for p in cart_product:
                tempamount= (p.quantity * p.product.final_price)
                amount += tempamount
                total_amount = amount+ shipping_amount
        context = {'cart':cart, 'total_amount':total_amount, 'amount':amount,'shipping_amount':shipping_amount}
        return render(request, 'general/addtocart.html', context)
    else:
        return redirect('login')
def plus_cart(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        prod_id =  request.GET['prod_id']
        c= Cart.objects.get(Q(product=prod_id) & Q(user = request.user)) 
        c.quantity+=1
        c.save()
        amount = 0.0
        shipping_amount = 10.0
        cart_product = [p for p in Cart.objects.all() if p.user == request.user]
        for p in cart_product:
            tempamount= (p.quantity * p.product.final_price)
            amount += tempamount
            total_amount = amount+ shipping_amount
        data={
            'quantity':c.quantity,
            'amount': amount,
            'total_amount': total_amount
        },
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

Javascript.js

```
$('.plus-cart').click(function () {
    //console.log("Click")
    var id = $(this).attr("pid").toString();
    var eml = this.parentNode.children[2]
    //console.log(id)
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"/plus_cart",
        data:{
            prod_id: id
        },
        success: function (data){
            //console.log(data)
            //console.log('success')
            eml.innerText = data.quantity
            document.getElementById("amount").innerText = data
            document.getElementById("total_amount").innerText = data
        }
    })
})
```

addtocart.html

```
<div class="card-body">
    {% for cart in cart %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-center align-self-center">
            <img src="{{cart.product.product_image.url}}" alt="" srcset="" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail shadow-sm" height="150" width="150" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="m-2 py-2">
                <h6>{{cart.product.title}}</h6>
                <p class="mb-2 text-muted small">Description: {{cart.product.description}}</p>
                <div class="my-3">
                    <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>

                    <a class="minus-cart btn" pid="{{cart.product.id}}"><i class="fas fa-minus-square fa-lg"></i></a>

                    <span id="quantity">{{cart.quantity}}</span>

                    <a class="plus-cart btn" pid="{{cart.product.id}}"><i class="fas fa-plus-square fa-lg"></i></a>

                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary mr-3" pid="{{cart.product.id}}">Remove Item</a>
                    <span class="p-lg-5"><strong>Rs. {{cart.product.final_price}}</strong></span>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

urls.py

`path("plus_cart/", views.plus_cart),`

is there any way to fix the 500 server error, or my server side error, i am using localhost

Answer (score 0):

you can handle the error with `statusCode:` in your ajax request to know about your error from backend. usually error code with 500 indicates there is error on your backend.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"/plus_cart",
    data:{
        prod_id: id
    },
    // add this block code
    statusCode: { 
        500: function(response) {
           console.log(response)
        }
    }, 
    // add this block code
    success: function (data){
        //console.log(data)
        //console.log('success')
        eml.innerText = data.quantity
        document.getElementById("amount").innerText = data
        document.getElementById("total_amount").innerText = data
    }
})
```

after that you can check on your browser console to check the error so you can catch error from backend